# MS Access 2010 now asks for parameters on form load

Tags: ms-access, parameters

I've been writing MS Access apps for a long time. I just switched to Access 2010 and now wherever I open a form in which I'm creating the InputParameters in code, the app prompts me to enter the parameters. I'm baffled and can't figure this out.

The following code has worked on all previous versions of MS Access until Access 2010:

```
  Dim strRS As String
  Dim lngID as Long
  Dim intSomethignElse as Integer

  strRS = "dbo.StoredProcedureName"
  lngID = 1
  intSomethignElse = 2

  Forms!SomeFormName.InputParameters = "@parameter1 = " & lngID  & ", @parameter2  = " & intSomethignElse

 'Verify the parameters do indeed exist and they do:
  Debug.Print Forms!SomeFormName.InputParameters

  Forms!SomeFormName.RecordSource = strRS
```

Now when the form loads I get prompted to enter @parameter1 and @parameter2.
How do I get this to work again in MS Access 2010?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is something on the lines of `Forms!SomeFormName.RecordSource = "exec dbo.StoredProcedureName @parameter=" & lngID` any use to you?

Comment: I assume this is a Access data project then? The InputParameters feature ONLY works for a data project, and does not work for regular mdb, or accDB (standard) access databases. If you use inputParameters for a non ADP or you are using linked tables to SQL server, then the InputParameters feature is not available.

Comment: If my suggestion does not suit, it would be good to know why not. I tested with SQL Server and a 2010 adp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the similar VBA code. It worked fine in Access 2010 until recently and I got the same issue as the pop up window asking for parameters.

After I change the code to simliar to

```
Forms!SomeFormName.RecordSource = "exec dbo.StoredProcedureName @parameter=" & lngID
```

as Remou suggested in the comments, my application works again.

Answer (score 1):

May be the RecordSource is not empty. Make sure it is empty in design view.

---

EDIT:

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff837198.aspx) says: The stored procedure should be executed using a command string containing the {call } syntax with one ? marker for each non-default parameter in the InputParameters list.

I do not know the call syntax, but I would try something like this:

```
strRS = "exec dbo.StoredProcedureName ?, ?"
```

Comment: I did check that, thanks. I made sure both the InputParameters and RecordSources were blank when the form loads.